# Как взять все числа из текста?

Tags: python

Написал бота в телеграме который считывает курс доллара и отправляет его, но я как понял эти цифры в текст формате и я не могу их умножить. Например хочу 2 умножить на курс, то есть 2 * dollar_rub
И вместо условных 60, я получаю 3030

Comment: `int('30')*2 == 60`

Comment: Спасибо, как буду дома попробую.

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит описать в вопросе: что делали, примеры данных - больше конкретики, иначе сложно предложить решение

Comment: И у меня еще такая проблема что я не могу несколько сообщений(переменных) ввести в бота. a = "hi" b = "albert", я вставляю эти переменные в бот мессдж и вылазит ошибка, то есть (a, b)